# Input fields not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I am showing a simple `<input type="text" />` in a ModalPopupExtender which is shown in top of a ColorBox. It shows fine, but the user can't write in it. Can anyone tell what's wrong?

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script src="Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#testbutton').click(function () {
            $.colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%", open: true, href: "#messageform",
                onClosed: function () {
                    $('#messageform').hide();
                },
                onOpen: function () {
                    $('#messageform').show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <input id="testbutton" type="button" value="click" />

    <div id="messageform" style="display: none;">
        <asp:Button ID="open" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="open">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

    <div id="Panel1">
        <input type="text" name="foo" value="" />   <--- **This shows, but can't enter text**
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you click on the textbox, or if you inspect the element, does it go to the textbox or is something overlapping it?

Comment: It shows the right cursor, but when clicked the "blinking-cursor" isn't showing. I've checked the element, doesn't seems like theres something in front of it. The code can be tested, just with downloading newest version of Colorbox.

Comment: In the final markup does the input tag have readonly attribute? <input type="text" readonly  />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote to the author of Colorbox, and he tracked the issue down to the following lines:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('focus', //trapFocus, true);
                $events.one(event_closed, function (){
                document.removeEventListener('focus', trapFocus, true);
                ;}
```

I outcommented those, and now it seems to work (don't know about older IE versions and other problems though).

Comment: using a more recent version of colorbox, it is possible to use a setting of trapFocus:false, which disables that same section of code.  This is usually a better solution than making a custom version of the js.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will have a look :-)

Answer (score 1):

the name attribute is misssing. and maybe you could try to give it an empty value

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="" />
```

what does onClosed and onOpen do? 
how does your css look like? 
or is the popup layer (or an overlay) over the input? check z-index.

Comment: I've added name and value, still isn't editable. For this example, there is no css, just wrote it so it was easy to test. z-index is OK. If i change the input with <select /> dropdown, it works in Chrome but not IE and Firefox if that helps finding the problem..?

Comment: save the page as html and build an easy example code on jsfiddle for it if possible. i dont know what asp generates.

Comment: I have answered my own question below. Was an 'error' in new Colorbox. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign `name` and `value` attribute as well Like

```
<input type="text" name="myText" value="Enter Your Name">
```

Or if you want to assign `empty` value then try

```
<input type="text" name=myText value="">
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I've added name and value, still isn't editable.  If i change the input with <select /> dropdown, it works in Chrome but not IE and Firefox if that helps finding the problem..?